# Assertions "is.visible" pass on elements which are not visible in cypress

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, chai, visible

Is there a workaround for this? I want to force Cypress to wait until the loading screen ends but it's asserting a bunch of elements that are not yet visible on screen.

The assertion is:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="cam-button"]').should('be.visible');
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the HTML for the cam button. And also is this the button you want to wait till it appears on the screen?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a timeout if you how long it takes

```
cy.get('[data-cy="cam-button"]', { timeout: xxx }).should('be.visible');
```

Answer (score 2):

the most important thing is to add to `cypress.json` flexible/Explicit wait

`"defaultCommandTimeout": 25000,`

it will wait until your element will be visible and also will apply globally for the whole framework
cypress docs https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts

Answer (score 0):

You should assert the button is not visible first, then assert the loader is not visible & then assert the button is visible like so:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="cam-button"]').should('not.be.visible');
cy.get('<loader-selector-here>').should('not.be.visible');
cy.get('[data-cy="cam-button"]').should('be.visible');
```

You can even use [an alias](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Elements) if you use the same selector through the code like so:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="cam-button"]').as('camButton');

cy.get('@camButton').should('not.be.visible');
cy.get('<loader-selector-here>').should('not.be.visible');
cy.get('@camButton').should('be.visible');
```